# Why does my page only display the title and not the data created in cloud Firestore?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to HTML and I am using this code to display reviews of books from my google cloud platform. However, whenever I run the code, only the title 'my book reviews' is displayed. I have also a JavaScript file for connecting to Firestore. Can someone pls help me out

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
 
   <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" " crossorigin="anonymous">
 
   <!-- Firebase JS -->
   <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.3.0/firebase.js"></script>
   <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebase/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
   <title>store reviews</title>
 </head>
 <body>
       <div class="container">
         <h1 id="mainTitle">My store reviews</h1>
         <table id="reviewList" class="table"></table>
       </div>
​
       <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
       <script crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
       <script src="myscripts.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

and there's the javascript file:

```
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
var db = firebase.firestore();

// Get a live data snapshot (i.e. auto-refresh) of our Reviews collection
db.collection("Reviews") {


    // Empty HTML table
    $('#reviewList').empty();
   ​
    // Loop through snapshot data and add to HTML table
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      $('#reviewList').append('<tr>');
      $('#reviewList').append('<td>'  + doc.data().store_name + '</td>');

      $('#reviewList').append('</tr>');
    });
   ​
    // Display review count
    $('#mainTitle').html(querySnapshot.size + " book reviews in the list");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes probably from the fact that you are appending incomplete elements to the DOM, which is probably trying to **fix what it interprets as an error** as soon as it happens.

By the time you append the closing tag, which you assume it will construct a correct HTML element, the opening tag has probably been removed from the DOM.

On each loop you call:

```js
$('#reviewList').append('<tr>');
```

`append()` adds a `<tr>` to the DOM when you call it, but, at that moment, there is no closing tag, which the browser will interpret as incorrect HTML and will try to correct, I think that different browsers may do different things here, but it could be that they all just remove the tag, you could try calling that line from the console to see what is the outcome.

By the time you call:

```js
$('#reviewList').append('</tr>');
```

The opening `<tr>` tag that you tried to add before is probably gone from the DOM, so the engine will also see this as incorrect HTML and *fix it*.

I haven't tried your code, and I could be wrong, and the error could be somewhere else, but it is probably there, and it should be easy for you to try the code below to see if it works with your Firestone data.

You *could* construct *and append* a row on each iteration of the foreach, but you want to try to minimize insertions, I think it is better to construct a string with your HTML and do only one insertion, that way the DOM only needs to be repainted once.

```js
// Get a live data snapshot (i.e. auto-refresh) of our Reviews collection
db.collection("Reviews")
  .orderBy("book_rating", "desc")
  .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {

    let html = '';

    // No need to empty the table if you are going to rewrite the contents later
    // $('#reviewList').empty();
   ​
    // Loop through snapshot data and add to HTML table
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      const data = doc.data();
      html += `<tr><td>${data.book_name}</td><td>${data.book_rating}/5</td></tr>`;
    });

   ​ // Only use the $('#reviewList') selector once, expensive, if you want to 
    // reuse it, cache it using a constant
    $('#reviewList').html(html);
    // Display review count
    $('#mainTitle').html(querySnapshot.size + " book reviews in the list");
});
```